# How many non oriented graphs are there in a set V if |E|=6?

Tags: graph-theory

> How many non oriented graphs are there in a set $V=\{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$ if $|E|=6$?

My reasoning is for the first edge you can choose from 10 vertices: $^{10}C_2$, second edge you can choose from 8 so: 
$$
^{10}C_2+^{8}C_2+^{6}C_2+^{4}C_2+^{2}C_2+^{0}C_2+^{-2}C_2
= \sum_{i=0}^{5} \binom{10-2i}{2}
$$

Which should be the total number of edges, granted we have 6 of them. However we reach a contradiction. On the last edge there are no more vertices to choose from (n  becomes negative) so we have to repeat edges??

**EDIT:** I thought about it and could the answer be impossible? How can a graph with 10 vertices have 6 edges? Only if one of the edges was repeated

Comment: Your summation is almost correct. Note that the order in which you pick the $6$ edges is unimportant, so you need to divide the sum by $6!$.

Comment: There are a total of $|V|\choose2$ possible edges in a graph, so no, it's not $0$.

Comment: Do you regard isomorphic graphs as different if the vertices are labeled differently?

Comment: Your response to the above question by almagest is required for the question to be answered.

Comment: They are not different if you label the vertices differently.